# Discover all used php extensions from code

Tags: php, continuous-integration

Is there any tool to list all used php extensions from existing code?

The usecase is to fix `composer.json` to add reliably all missing extensions requires.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by php extensions. Are this the php modules? If it's that there's a way to list them up in the commaind line by `php -m`.

Comment: Example: in code `bcpow` is used, output contains `bcmath` php extension.

Comment: PHP cannot somehow reverse engineer how a function got implemented or defined in the current environment. So the answer is: no. You could only build a catalogue. But that would obviously be a cat and mouse game...

Comment: I think using https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs data the used functions can be easily identified, I wonder if anyone knows if someone already done that and released it as a tool.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you what I do.
I use Eclipse (but you can use any IDE with auto completion).
Eclipse will put a small red icon next to each file (or folder that has a bad file in it) that has a syntax error or an un-identified symbol.
That way I can see pretty fast where stuff is missing.
You can also go the other way and start from an empty composer, do install and add one package after the other, until all missing symbol alerts disappear.

I am sure there are some linters/code analyzers which can do it much more efficiently and faster (although an through analysis takes me about 10-15 minutes, and I do it maybe once a year).